# How can I count comma separated values in one column of my panda table?

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following code:

```
businessdata = ['Name of Location','Address','City','Zip Code','Website','Yelp',
'# Reviews', 'Yelp Rating Stars','BarRestStore','Category',
'Price Range','Alcohol','Ambience','Latitude','Longitude']

business = pd.read_table('FL_Yelp_Data_v2.csv', sep=',', header=1, names=businessdata)
print '\n\nBusiness\n'
print business[:6]
```

It reads my file and creates a Panda table I can work with.
What I need is to count how many categories are in each line of the 'Category' variable and store this number in a new column named '# Categories'. Here is the target column sample:

```
Category                                         
French                                               
Adult Entertainment , Lounges , Music Venues         
American (New) , Steakhouses                        
American (New) , Beer, Wine & Spirits , Gastropubs 
Chicken Wings , Sports Bars , American (New)         
Japanese
```

Desired output:

```
Category                                        # Categories  
French                                               1           
Adult Entertainment , Lounges , Music Venues         3         
American (New) , Steakhouses                         2        
American (New) , Beer, Wine & Spirits , Gastropubs   4         
Chicken Wings , Sports Bars , American (New)         3         
Japanese                                             1
```

EDIT 1:

Raw input = CSV file. Target column: "Category"
I can't post screenshots yet. I don't think the values to be counted are lists.

This is my code:

```
business = pd.read_table('FL_Yelp_Data_v2.csv', sep=',', header=1, names=businessdata, skip_blank_lines=True)
#business = pd.read_csv('FL_Yelp_Data_v2.csv')

business['Category'].str.split(',').apply(len)
#not sure where to declare the df part in the suggestions that use it.

print business[:6]
```

but I keep getting the following error:

```
TypeError: object of type 'float' has no len()
```

EDIT 2:

I GIVE UP. Thanks for all your help, but I'll have to figure something else.

Comment: is our category data stored as a list or a string as displayed?

Comment: Please post raw input data and code used to load this data, as you can see you've received many answers and some of these may answer your question

Comment: So far I the problem is still unsolved.  
I have added some information to the post.  
I tried to do `print type(business['Category']) is [all types of var]` but I always get False in return.

Answer (score 4):

Assuming that Category is actually a list, you can use `apply` (per @EdChum's suggestion):

```
business['# Categories'] = business.Category.apply(len)
```

If not, you first need to parse it and convert it into a list.

```
df['Category'] = df.Category.map(lambda x: [i.strip() for i in x.split(",")])
```

Can you show some sample output of EXACTLY what this column looks like (including correct quotations)?

P.S. @EdChum  Thank you for your suggestions.  I appreciate them.  I believe the list comprehension method may be faster, per a sample of some text data I tested with 30k+ rows of data:

```
%%timeit
df.Category.str.strip().str.split(',').apply(len)
10 loops, best of 3: 44.8 ms per loop

%%timeit
df.Category.map(lambda x: [i.strip() for i in x.split(",")])
10 loops, best of 3: 28.4 ms per loop
```

Even accounting for the `len` function call:

```
%%timeit
df.Category.map(lambda x: len([i.strip() for i in x.split(",")]))
10 loops, best of 3: 30.3 ms per loop
```

Comment: You should use the vectorised str methods: `df.Category.str.strip().str.split(',').apply(len)`

Comment: Sorry for my lack of knowledge, but what would this "df" be?

Comment: A generic Pandas DataFrame, e.g. 'business' in your case.

Comment: I can't use any of these methods... I keep getting `'float' object has no attribute 'split' `

Comment: Which tells you that your 'Category' column contains some floating point numbers instead of a string.

Comment: If some of the rows have NaN, what should they be replaced with such that this function assigns them 0? I've tried transforming them to '' but that counts as "1"

Comment: @Acoustic77 Would you mind asking a new question with your sample data and expected output?  You can link it to this one.  Thx.

Answer (score 2):

This works:

```
business['# Categories'] = business['Category'].apply(lambda x: len(x.split(',')))
```

If you need to handle NA, etc, you can pass a more elaborate function instead of the lambda.

Comment: it'd be better to use the vectorised str split method: `business['Category'].str.split(',').apply(len)`

Comment: This is what I am getting with your suggestion:

`29 business = pd.read_csv('FL_Yelp_Data_v2.csv')  
30 #business['# Category'] = business.Category.map(lambda x: [i.strip() for i in x.split(",")])  
---> 31 business['# Categories'] = business['Category'].apply(lambda x: len(x.split(',')))  
32  
33 print type(business['Category']) is float  
  
AttributeError: 'float' object has no attribute 'split' `

Comment: Obviously I didn't have your dataset when I wrote the answer. I assumed that values in the 'Category' column were comma separated strings.

Answer (score 2):

```
business['Categories'] = business.Category.str.count(',')+1
```

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.

Answer (score 0):

Use pd.read_csv to make the input easier:

```
business = pd.read_csv('FL_Yelp_Data_v2.csv')
```

http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_csv.html

Once this is created, you can create a function to split the categories column by the "," and count the length of the resulting list. Use lambda and apply.

Comment: How could I do this function vk1011?

Comment: You could do it in two ways:

(1) Use an inline split-and-count:
`business['number of categories'] = business['Categories'].apply(lambda x: len(x.split(',')))`

(2) Define a function and call that:
`def split_and_count(string_to_split_and_count):
 split_up = string_to_split_and_count.split(',')
 num_categories = len(split_up)
 return num_categories`

In your script, you use it like this: `business['number of categories'] = business['Categories'].apply(lambda x: split_and_count(x))`

Answer (score 0):

You can do this...

```
for i in business['Category'].tolist():
    business.loc[i, '#Categories'] = len(i.split(","))
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar doubt. I had count number of comma-separated words in each row . I resolved it in the following manner:

data['Number_of_Categories'] = data['Category'].apply(lambda x : len(str(x).split(',')))

Basically I am first converting each row to string since Python is recognizing it as a float and then performing the 'len' function. Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

```
df['column_name'].apply(lambda n: \len(n.split(',')))
```

Comment: This is a "code only" answer. If you could surround your code with an explanation of what's going on, the questioner will have a better idea of what you are trying to accomplish and how it helps them with their problem.

Answer (score 0):

This might be a bit of a cobbled together solution, but I had a similar problem and fixed it using something like this:

```
#Create an empty list to store your count in
numCategories=[]
#Create a loop to split each cell separately, then append to a list
i=0
while i <len(df):
#Switch out CategoriesColumnNumber in the below code for the correct column number
    temp_count = len(df.iloc[i,CategoriesColumnNumber].split(";"))
    numCategories.append(temp_count)
    i += 1
#Attach your newly generated list as a new column in your dataframe
df['#Categories'] = numCategories
```

Not the prettiest solution, but hopefully it might help some people that are just getting started!

Answer (score 0):

```
df['#Categories'] = df['Category'].map(lambda x: len(x.split(",")) if isinstance(x, str) else 0)
```

**I have put error handling - if condition where isinstance function will first check if each category is of string type, and then only it will exceute the len function else it will return 0**

Comment: Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. **Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?**